# p:selectOneMenu doesn't show currently selected value but first value instead

Tags: selectonemenu

I have a problem with p:selectOneMenus that are in a column of a p:treeTable.

```
<p:treeTable id="configTree" value="#{catalogBean.root}" var="element"
            expanded="true">
```

The currently selected value is stored in a hashMap. After selecting a value in the selectOneMenu the hashMap is correct. When I refresh the page the hashMap is still correct but the selectOneMenu displays the default (first) value and not the value of the hashMap entry.

```
<p:selectOneMenu rendered="#{catalogBean.hasNoLeaves(element) and catalogBean.isZeroOne(element) and element.isActivated}"
   value="#{configurationBean.map[element]}" effect="fold" style="min-width:200px;" valueChangeListener="#{configurationBean.processValueChange}" immediate="true">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="keine Auswahl" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{catalogBean.getCharacteristics(element)}" var="aus"
        itemLabel="#{aus.characteristic}" itemValue="#{aus}}"/>
    <f:ajax render="@form"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The hashMap:

```
private Map<AbstractProductStructureElement, List<AbstractProductStructureElement>> map = new HashMap<AbstractProductStructureElement, List<AbstractProductStructureElement>>();
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?